# How can I define a user macro path property to a stable location, for multiple solutions and projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to use Visual Studio's property pages to define some commonly-used paths as user macros - e.g., to the location of third-party libraries, or the base directory of the repository.

However, I'm only managing to define user macros either:

- Using an absolute path -- obviously wrong
- Relative to the project directory
- Relative to the solution directory.

None of those work for me, since our codebase has multiple VS solutions and some projects are shared between solutions.

For example, if I have the following structure:

```
$(BASE_DIR)/dirA/Solution1/Project1
$(BASE_DIR)/dirB/dirC/Solution2/Project2
$(BASE_DIR)/ThirdPartyLibs
```

... and I want to define a `$(ThirdPartyLibDir)` macro. Or, heck, a `$(BASE_DIR)` macro.

Let's say Solution 1 has only Project 1, and Solution 2 includes Project 1 and Project 2. In this case, I can't define these macros relative to `$(SolutionDir)`, nor to `$(ProjectDir)`.

**Is there any way I can define such a macro?**

(If there were a macro for getting the location of a property page file, I could put a `.props` file in `$(BASE_DIR)`, and define the macros that way. It doesn't look like that exists.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to do the following -

1. Create one property sheet per solution and create a user macro BASE_DIR inside it with a relative path (....\ etc.).
2. Create a common property sheet that contains the actual library locations etc. based on the BASE_DIR macro. Add this sheet to the projects too.

This allows you to specify include directories and other "common" properties using the $(BASE_DIR) macro in the common props file. The solution-specific property sheet provides the $(BASE_DIR) value relative to the projects in the solution.